# Ionic app not opening(Crashing) in android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am working on Ionic 3 app which was working grt in all device but suddenly It will closing immediately when I am trying to open.
App is serving good in browser and the build path.
"platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk"
One thing I noticed why apk is building inside debug folder ?

I tried removing node_module, platforms.

This is my ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.0
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 7
```

Plugin list:

```
call-number 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
cordova-plugin-app-update 1.6.0 "AppUpdate"
cordova-plugin-appversion 1.0.0 "App Version"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated 2.4.0 "Cordova FCM Push Plugin"
cordova-plugin-file 5.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.0.2 "FilePath"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.1.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.2.2 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.7 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

config.xml

```
 <widget android-versionCode="" id="" version="1.2.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>****</name>
<description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
<author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
<allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.16:8100" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^5.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.7.1" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^5.4.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-update" spec="^1.6.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder" spec="^3.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^4.0.1">
    <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To locate you" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.4.1" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.1.0" />
<engine androidspec="^6.3.0" name="" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.3" />
<plugin name="mx.ferreyra.callnumber" spec="~0.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
<platform name="android">
    <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<engine name="android" spec="7.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" spec="^2.4.0" />
```

Why app not opening properly in android device please suggest what could be goes wrong?

Comment: does it shows and error message after closing ? did you use inspect with chrome ?

Comment: No it will not showing error and in my system ionic run not working as it has to

Comment: run the app on emulator and inspect it on chrome and show it her

Comment: No I don't have emulator in system it having separate problem to solve :-(.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.remove android platform using

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

2. remove manually `node-modules` and `package-lock.json`  (imp*)
3. **Unistall** old Application
4. `npm cache clean --force`

finally run `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

In my ionic v3 app, when I was facing the same issue, the issue was in **network_security_config.xml** file, my app was also not starting at all , I had to remove one domain

`<domain includeSubdomains="true">myurl.com</domain>`

I had to remove such domain from the mentioned file, hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

did you try to remove android platform and add it after ?
Just like that :

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

I had the same problem, and don't know why but i did that and that was working.

Answer (score 0):

To Generate Release Apk in Ionic:

- Create release-signing.properties file with below snippet inside the platform/android

  key.store=xxx.keystore
  key.store.password=xxx
  key.alias=xxx
  key.alias.password=xxx
- Paste your Keystore file inside the platform/android directory
- Finally, Run **ionic cordova build android -- release** to generate the release apk

Can you share the log report when the app is closing. You can see the Log for your debug app in chrome://inspect.

Answer (score 0):

If you had changed spalshscreen or either put in wrong location of splash screen image in  **config.xml**means The app will open and check for Splash screen image if not get means the app will be closed.
So the better way to get solution is to copy the old project config.xml code and put it to the new project then it will work proper...
Then also if you not open means.

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

then

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a runtime error from your app. Try getting more info about the problem by running the app with debug information (`ionic serve`) for example.